# how to load 1000 lines of a csv into elasticsearch as 1000 different documents using elasticsearch API

Tags: python, csv, elasticsearch

so ive been trying to load 1000 lines of a csv into elasticsearhc as 1000 different documents, the csv has 8 headers: telease year, title, origin/ethnicity, director, cast, wiki page, plot.
my current code for loading the dataset loads it using the bulk command from helpers

```
import csv
from elasticsearch import helpers, Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch("http://localhost:9200")

es.indices.delete(index='movie-plots', ignore=[400, 404])
es.indices.create(index='movie-plots', body=body) 

filename = 'wiki_movie_plots_deduped.csv'

def csv_reader(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as outfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(outfile)
        helpers.bulk(es, reader, index="movie-plots", doc_type="_doc")
```

this i think loads 1000 lines into one document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path, the code below will split the csv into 1000 different items but splitting out the headers and turning each line item into a map/dictionary item with appropriate headers. This is then appended to a list so you upload a list of dictionary items.

```
import csv, sys
from elasticsearch import helpers, Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection

es = Elasticsearch(
    hosts=[{
        'host': 'localhost',
        'port': '9200'}],
    use_ssl=False,
    verify_certs=True,
    connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection
)

upload_list = [] # list of items for upload

# Load all csv data
with open('my_folder/my_csv_file.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    
    data_list = []

    csv_data = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in csv_data:
        data_list.append(row)

    # separate out the headers from the main data 
    headers = data_list[0]
    # drop headers from data_list
    data_list.pop(0)

    for item in data_list: # iterate over each row/item in the csv

        item_dict = {}

        # match a column header to the row data for an item
        i = 0
        for header in headers:
            item_dict[header] = item[i]
            i = i+1

        # add the transformed item/row to a list of dicts
        upload_list += [item_dict]

# using helper library's Bulk API to index list of Elasticsearch docs
try:
    resp = helpers.bulk(
        es,
        upload_list,
        index="my-index-name"
    )
    msg = "helpers.bulk() RESPONSE: " + str(resp)
    print(msg) # print the response returned by Elasticsearch
except Exception as err:
    msg = "Elasticsearch helpers.bulk() ERROR: " + str(err)
    print(msg)
    sys.exit(1)
```